# Can anyone offer guidance on monkeypatching/hooking Ruby's string #{} for interpolation?

Tags: c, ruby

I'm working on monkeypatching some core components of the Ruby language(I know, I know, monkeypatching is bad) - what I specifically need to do is hook into:

`"#{some_variable}"`

My naive approach is to parse the AST with the whitequark parser gem & rewrite all #{} to concats(which does work) but I don't like some of the requirements of this route(monkey patching a lot of other things to get every file on load[list of problems goes on]).

I've dug into the ruby C code but have been unable to locate the function that actually performs interpolation.  Can anyone help me identify where/how that behavior is defined?

EDIT: 
What I'm trying to achieve, just as you can do:

```
class String
  alias_method :my_+, :+
  def +(other)
    puts 'patched'
    self.my_+(other)
  end
end
a = "a"
a + "b" => #would output patched
```

I would like a similar way to patch #{} - however, this cannot be done through normal monkeypatching - I'm looking for general guidance on how to achieve this without rewriting the AST of every class in the VM.

Comment: Could be `compile.c`, could be `insns.def`… it isn't clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"str1 #{funcall} str2"` does the following in Ruby :

```
== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>:1 (1,0)-(1,24)>=================
0000 putobject        "str1 "                                         (   1)[Li]
0002 putself
0003 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:funcall, argc:0, FCALL|VCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0006 dup
0007 branchiftype     T_STRING, 15
0010 dup
0011 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:to_s, argc:0, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0014 tostring
0015 putobject        " str2"
0017 concatstrings    3
0019 leave
```

There's a lot of operation (casting the #{} content to string if not a string) and it finish with the concatstrings command which according to this : http://lifegoo.pluskid.org/upload/doc/yarv/yarv_iset.html#detail-19 call `rb_str_append`

In other words, you cannot monkey patch / hook #{} using Ruby but as suggested by cremno you should look into the C part to overwrite the default behavior of #{ } by recompiling Ruby with your own hook.